# Trouble with scraping only content without another elements inside <td>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<td>945.000 (<font color="blue">+3.000</font>)</td>
```

I want to get only the 945.000 inside the  tag but there is another element inside it, how can I do it?. Using .string returns none and I think it's because the font color inside it.

Comment: try td.contents[0]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken data as `html` you can find `td` tag and find text using `.text` method or `.get_text` then split the data which returns as `list` format

```
html="""<td>945.000 (<font color="blue">+3.000</font>)</td>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
soup.find("td").text.split(" ")[0]
```

Output:

```
945.000
```